# Rails - Rufus cron event A runs daily but event B does not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rufus-scheduler

```
require_relative '../../bin/generate_survey'
require_relative '../../bin/generate_stats_emails'
email_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/email_config.yml")

def rufus_logger
  @@rufus_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/rufus.log")
end

survey_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
rufus_logger.info('Initializing Survey Rufus Scheduler')

#Job A
survey_scheduler.cron '00 08 * * 1-5' do
  conference_today = read_ics_make_quiz(Date.today)
  rufus_logger.info("Survey scheduling for #{Date.today} returns #{conference_today}")
end

#Job B
survey_scheduler.cron '00 23 * * 1-5' do
  rufus_logger.info("Stats Emails starting")
  survey_settings = Survey.where ['unlock_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day] unless @survey_settings[0]
  if survey_settings.present?
    get_latest_stats(email_config)
    UserMailer.presenter_stats_email(email_config[:action_mailer][:education_email_group]).deliver_now
    UserMailer.resident_stats_email(email_config[:action_mailer][:resident_email_group]).deliver_now
    rufus_logger.info("Stats Emails sent")
  else
    rufus_logger.info("Stats Emails not sent")
  end
end
```

Details:
server: Ubuntu 12.04
Apache/mysql/Passenger
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.2.0

Job A runs perfectly well, every time.
Job B never executes.  It never leaves anything in the log.

Rufus.log has:
Initializing Survey Rufus Scheduler
followed by daily lines of:
Survey scheduling for #{Date.today} returns #{conference_today}

It never reaches Job B comments

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please update your question and indicate what server Rails runs on (Webrick, Unicorn, Passenger, ...).

Comment: Really, "Stats Emails starting" is never emitted to the log?

Comment: Edited for clarity, and yes it never gets the "Stats Emails starting" log.  The regular Rails log also never shows the query at 11pm (thankfully the survey is open from 2-4 so its easy to tell when this should be running)

Answer (score 1):

Your "split in two files" move is interesting, but you'd better qualify it as "split in two files and two scheduler instances". I'm happy you got it working somehow.

I wonder if the job got scheduled or not in you first "single file" version. Something like

```
p survey_scheduler.jobs.length
```

would have told us. But I think it would have told 2 and the problem lies elsewhere, which brings me to the second part of my "answer".

Thanks for adding a sorely missing piece of information by specifying that you are using Passenger.

Passenger vs rufus-scheduler is a classic. The usual symptom is "it doesn't schedule" or "it doesn't schedule after a while". I suspect that you're victim to a variant of this. Can't tell until you report very carefully what's happening.

I urge you to read the 3 last link in the rufus-scheduler README [FAQ](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#faq), they hold information (and solutions) about these problems. A peek at the manual for the Passenger version you're using would be good to. Know your tools.

The [last link](https://jkraemer.net/2012/10/running-rufus-scheduler-in-a-unicorn-rails-app) is more about Unicorn, but it hints at solutions for Passenger too.

Comment: I'm hesitant to accept my solution as the answer for this reason.  I read through those links, but unfortunately there are several other sites that use cron jobs, and one that uses rufus successfully to run 3-4 jobs from one script.  I didn't want to mess with apache/passenger settings and muck up another site unless it was absolutely necessary.

Comment: I would not qualify your answer as a "solution", it is not guaranteed to work for the next person facing such an issue, it is not even guaranteed to work in the medium term for you. Your issue report is too vague, the scheduled code in your answer differs significantly from the code in the question (beyond the split). You are not checking at all for errors in the scheduled code, nor making sure the loggers are flushed...

Comment: Also I will run it with the original file and let you know what the jobs.length puts out.

One major thing you may want to add to your instructions.  If I restart apache I must hit my website or Rufus will not run.  This nearly drove me insane.

Comment: Don't you think that this "If I restart Apache I must hit my website or Rufus will not run" is a symptom of a misconfigured Apache + Passenger couple? This is out of the scope of the rufus-scheduler "instructions", those instructions are already kind enough to point you at solutions and hints you could use, if you read carefully and cared for the mastery of your tools. Offense taken.

Comment: Do you realize that rufus doesn't run on its own? That it starts when Rails starts? That it's your responsibility to tune Apache+Passenger so that your Rails application is started as soon as possible? Do you understand that maybe, this "If I restart Apache I must hit my website..." might be accompanied by a "If nobody hits my website in a while, Apache stops it" which might link to a "Doh, the schedule at 2300 don't get run" realization?

Comment: I appreciate the attention to details and your quick answers.  Prior to this application I have never had the need to run scheduling.  This project has forced me to pick up Ruby/Rails/linux/apache/passenger so yes I appreciate the advice...But honestly a lot of this is new to me.  If I restart apache, it restarts rails and I get the log 'Initializing Survey Rufus Scheduler' but then Rufus does not run until I visit a page. I apologize for making the suggestion, and will get back with you RE investigating why it didn't work when I am able to.

Comment: "If I restart apache, it restarts rails and I get the log 'Initializing Survey Rufus Scheduler' but then Rufus does not run until I visit a page" would indicate that Passenger somehow kills the scheduler's thread early on and then brings it back... Glad you've put your "problem solver" hat on :-)

Answer (score 0):

I split them in to 2 files and they work now.

scheduled_jobs.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require_relative '../../bin/generate_survey'

def rufus_logger
  @@rufus_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/rufus.log")
end

survey_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
rufus_logger.info('Initializing Survey Rufus Scheduler')

survey_scheduler.cron '00 08 * * 1-5' do
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  conference_today = read_ics_make_quiz(Date.today)
  rufus_logger.info("Survey scheduling for #{Date.today} returns #{conference_today}")
end
```

scheduled_email.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require_relative '../../bin/generate_stats_emails'
email_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/email_config.yml")

def rufus_logger
  @@rufus_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/rufus.log")
end

email_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
rufus_logger.info('Initializing Email Rufus Scheduler')

email_scheduler.cron '00 23 * * 1-5' do
  rufus_logger.info("Stats Emails starting")
  get_latest_stats(email_config)
  UserMailer.presenter_stats_email(email_config[:action_mailer][:education_email_group]).deliver_now
  UserMailer.resident_stats_email(email_config[:action_mailer][:resident_email_group]).deliver_now
  rufus_logger.info("Stats Emails sent")
end
```

Comment: In the light of the "If I restart apache I must hit my website or Rufus will not run", I have the strong impression that it worked "this time" (last night) because your website had traffic before 2300 and Apache didn't put it to sleep until after the schedule triggered...

Comment: Maybe, the original script though it ran at 8am every morning correctly for the first job.  The survey is open from 1230-3 daily.  That is the only traffic to the site.  If it went to sleep for the 11pm job wouldn't it be asleep for the 8am job? To be fair I have not yet had a chance to run this at 11, I've been changing the times to be 5 minutes after restarting apache on the server (giving me enough time to then hit the page) for testing purposes.

Clearly I need to look into the server settings, and spend time learning it.  Thanks.